# PHP connecting with SQL and displaying data

Tags: php, sql, view-helpers

**HI, All**

I have created (copied) a website that can view the information inside my database. But the code i have, displays every single bot as well as members.

I am connecting it to local host and the database is phpbb3.

I need a sting to get rid of the bots which have a group_id of 6.

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
        <title>View Records</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
/* 
        VIEW.PHP
        Displays all data from 'phpbb_users' table
*/

        // connect to the database
        include('connect-db.php');

        // get results from database
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users") 
                or die(mysql_error());  

        // display data in table
        echo "<p><b>View All</b> | <a href='view-paginated.php?page=1'>View Paginated</a></p>";

        echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
        echo "<tr> <th>ID</th> <th>Username</th> <th>Email</th> <th></th> <th></th></tr>";

        // loop through results of database query, displaying them in the table
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

                // echo out the contents of each row into a table
                echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td>' . $row['user_id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['username'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $row['user_email'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';
                echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['user_id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
                echo "</tr>"; 
        } 

        // close table>
        echo "</table>";
?>
<p><a href="new.php">Add a new record</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Thank you,
In advanced.**

Comment: `SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE group_id <> 6`  I suggest you get a good book about SQL to start learning.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users")
```

To

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM phpbb_users WHERE group_id <> 6")
```